# Is it possible to fetch all the relationships available for an entity from CRM using web api?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have a requirement to fetch and show all the available Relationships of an Entity on HTML page, separately.
Eg: If I chose, Account, in the html page, I should be able to see 1:N, N:1 and N:N relationships of Account Entity.

I have tried below, queries and I feel, these are not helping me correctly, Please suggest me a workaround for this to achieve.

```
https://<CRMORGNAME>/api/data/v8.2/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ManyToOneRelationshipMetadata?$select=Entity1LogicalName,SchemaName&$filter=Entity1LogicalName eq 'account'

https://<CRMORGNAME>/api/data/v8.2/RelationshipDefinitions?$select=RelationshipType,SchemaName
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

One to many:

```
https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84)/OneToManyRelationships?$select=SchemaName,RelationshipType
```

Many to one:

```
https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84)/ManyToOneRelationships?$select=SchemaName,RelationshipType
```

Many to many:

```
https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84)/ManyToManyRelationships?$select=SchemaName,RelationshipType
```

Of course you should first get the proper EntityDefinition id (the '70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84' is for account in this case)

```
https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions?$select=SchemaName,LogicalName,MetadataId&$filter=LogicalName eq 'account'
```

Comment: Pawel Gradecki, Thank you for the information. Small concern here, calling 3 web api impact the performance of the application right?                                  Is there any way to get this 3 relationship details using one single WEB API call? for example, response.OneToManyRelationships like this. Kindly provide your valuable suggestions/help on this too...

Comment: I would not care about the performance in this case, you are not calling 100 requests, just 3 of them. Simply do it asynchronously and the browser will handle to call them in separate simultaneous threads and the impact on the performance would be minimal. If you will be calling them synchronously, then in fact this would be not the best idea.

Comment: Thank you Pawel Gradecki, Was thinking about the performance of the system. But, yes I agree with your point.I will try out it then.

Comment: @SaiKrishna, Two things: You are not required to get Metadata ID. The `EntityDefinitions` can be queried by `LogicalName`. You can get all relationships in a single request: `http://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToManyRelationships,ManyToOneRelationships,OneToManyRelationships`.

Comment: Yeah, I am completely missed, using Expand, can make use of Logical name directly there. Thank you for your valuable inputs @Jathin Sanghvi

Comment: @PawelGradecki When I am running this query to fetch Referenced Entities of Annotation, I am getting multiple "systemuser"entity results from the below query. Any idea on this? http://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='annotation')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencedEntity)